# How do I pull in the right number of dynamically generated variables using php and javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic

I have multiple textboxes that are dynamically generated; the number of boxes can differ each time. How do I match the number of variables created in javascript (box1, box2, etc) with the number of rows called from the table on the back-end?  An example: if there are only 2 rows as a result of $query, there should only be 2 javascript variables (box1 and box2).  At the same time, how do I dynamically generate the right url that corresponds to the right number?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `sessionid` WHERE `sessionid` = '$session'  ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo '<table class="table"><tbody>';
$subtotal = 0;
$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<tr><td></td><td><h3>' . $row['title'] . '</h3></td><td>' . $row['options'] . '</td><td><div class="span3 offset1"><input type="text" id="box' . $i . '"value="' . $row['qt'] . '" class="span1"> <input type="button" class="btn" value = "Refresh" onclick="ajaxFunction()" />   <h4> $' . $row['price'] . '<div id="ajaxDiv">Your result will display here</div></h4></td></tr>';
  $i++;
  $prodtotal= $row['qt'] * $row['price'];
  $subtotal= round($subtotal+ $prodtotal, 2);
  $_SESSION['subtotal']=$subtotal;
}

echo '</form></tbody></table>';

//javascript later on
var box1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
var box2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
var box3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
var box4 = document.getElementById('box4').value;
var queryString = "?box1=" + box1 + "&box2=" + box2 + "&box3=" + box3 + "&box4=" + box4;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could gather an array of box values in your JavaScript, e.g.

```
var boxValues = new Array();
var i = 1;
while (document.getElementById('box' + i) !== undefined) {
    var box = document.getElementById('box' + i);
    boxValues[i] = box.value;
    i++;
}
var queryString = '?';
for(i = 1; i < boxValues.length; i++) {
    queryString += 'box' + i + '=' + boxValues[i] + '&';
}
queryString = queryString.slice(0, -1); // eat the last '&'
```

This approach has the advantage of not needing to embed php in your JS (dubious comparisons aside, e.g. if you have another page element with id 'box6' and your table ends at 'box5', you will get funky results). Of course, if you don't need the references to the values other than to build the query string, you could just build the string while looping over the values and skip storing them in an array at all, e.g.

```
var i = 1;
var queryString = '?';
while (document.getElementById('box' + i) !== undefined) {
    var boxValue = document.getElementById('box' + i).value;
    queryString += 'box' + i + '=' + boxValue + '&';
    i++;
}
queryString = queryString.slice(0, -1); // eat the last '&'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should output your JavaScript as part of the loop that goes through your result. Therefore you would change this:

```
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<tr><td></td><td><h3>' . $row['title'] . '</h3></td><td>' . $row['options'] . '</td><td><div class="span3 offset1"><input type="text" id="box' . $i . '"value="' . $row['qt'] . '" class="span1"> <input type="button" class="btn" value = "Refresh" onclick="ajaxFunction()" />   <h4> $' . $row['price'] . '<div id="ajaxDiv">Your result will display here</div></h4></td></tr>';
                $i++;
                $prodtotal= $row['qt'] * $row['price'];
                $subtotal= round($subtotal+ $prodtotal, 2);
                $_SESSION['subtotal']=$subtotal;
                }
```

To something like:

```
$str = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<tr><td></td><td><h3>' . $row['title'] . '</h3></td><td>' . $row['options'] . '</td><td><div class="span3 offset1"><input type="text" id="box' . $i . '"value="' . $row['qt'] . '" class="span1"> <input type="button" class="btn" value = "Refresh" onclick="ajaxFunction()" />   <h4> $' . $row['price'] . '<div id="ajaxDiv">Your result will display here</div></h4></td></tr>';

$str .= 'var box'.$i.' = document.getElementById("box'.$i.'").value;'.PHP_EOL;

        $i++;
        $prodtotal= $row['qt'] * $row['price'];
        $subtotal= round($subtotal+ $prodtotal, 2);
        $_SESSION['subtotal']=$subtotal;
    }
```

And where your JavaScript is...

```
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:

1 . PHP and javascript

PHP:

```
$cnt = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  cnt++;
.
.
.
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var qString = "";
for (var i=1;i<=<?php echo $cnt; ?>;i++) {
  qString += '&box'+i+'='+document.getElementById('box'+i).value;
}
qString = "?"+qString.substring(1);
```

---

2 . PHP only:

```
<input type="text" id="box[]" value="'....
```

and simply submit the form or use jQuery Ajax with serialize.